# How to aggregate sum in MongoDB according to the data in the array to get a total count?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have data in the form:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "array": [{
        "who": "jon",
        "whom": "max",
        "point": 2,
        "description": "la-la"
    }]
} {
    "_id": 2,
    "array": [{
        "Id": "jon",
        "ToId": "peter",
        "point": 3,
        "description": "la-la"
    }]
} {
    "_id": 3,
    "array": [{
        "Id": "peter",
        "ToId": "max",
        "point": 2,
        "description": "la-la"
    }]
} {
    "_id": 4,
    "array": [{
        "Id": "max",
        "ToId": "peter",
        "point": 3,
        "description": "la-la"
    }]
}
```

I took the data from the array command:

```
db.game.aggregate([{$project: {_id: false, array: true}}, {$unwind: "$array"}])

{ "array" : { "Id" : "jon", "ToId" : "max", "pointCount" : 2, "description" : "la-la" } }
{ "array" : { "Id" : "jon", "ToId" : "peter", "pointCount" : 3, "description" : "la-la" } }
{ "array" : { "Id" : "peter", "ToId" : "max", "pointCount" : 2, "description" : "la-la" } }
{ "array" : { "Id" : "max", "ToId" : "peter", "pointCount" : 3, "description" : "la-la" } }
```

How to get the data in a format

```
{"ToId" : "peter", "pointCount" : 6}
{"ToId" : "max", "pointCount" : 4}
```

Thank you.

Comment: you just need to group by ToId and calculate sum. db.game.aggregate([{$unwind: "$array"}, {$group:{"_id" : "$array.ToId", "pointCount": {$sum:"$pointCount"}}}, {$project: {"_id": 0, "ToId":"$_id", "pointCount": 1}}])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data from array command is different from the input. If you have the given input, the following query will work.

```
db.game.aggregate([
 {$unwind: "$array"}, 
 {$group:{"_id" : "$array.ToId", "pointCount": {$sum:"$array.point"}}}, 
 {$project: {_id: 0, "ToId":"$_id", "pointCount": 1}}
 ])
```

Comment: thanks, It works.
Tell me where you can see more details or read about these features

Comment: So, unwinding is removing all the arrays and making it a bigger array. Then on this big array group operation is being done is similar to groupby clause. After that you do projections (state of how you want to represent). All these 3 process are done in pipeline. So the input of one is given to other. They have it all properly documented with examples, you can refer https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/group/